# Take first dimension in ndarray python

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have a ndarray like this:

```
    a = [[20 43 61 41][92 23 43 33]]
```

I want take the first dimension of this ndarray. so I try something like this:

```
    a[0,:]
```

I hope it will return something like this:

```
    [[20 43 61 41]]
```

but i got this error:

```
   TypeError: 'numpy.int32' object is not iterable
```

Anyone can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using slice:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[20, 43, 61, 41], [92, 23, 43, 33]])
>>> a[:1]  # OR a[0:1]
array([[20, 43, 61, 41]])
>>> print(a[:1])
[[20 43 61 41]]
```

Answer (score 2):

It's strange that you're getting this error. It suggests that `a` isn't what you think it is (i.e. not a Numpy array).

Anyway, here is how it can be done:

```
In [10]: import numpy as np

In [11]: a = np.array([[20, 43, 61, 41], [92, 23, 43, 33]])

In [12]: a[0:1]
Out[12]: array([[20, 43, 61, 41]])
```

Contrast this with

```
In [14]: a[0]
Out[14]: array([20, 43, 61, 41])
```

(which may or may not be what you want.)